# Import method from Python submodule in __init__, but not submodule itself

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a Python module with the following structure:

```
mymod/
    __init__.py
    tools.py
```

```py
# __init__.py
from .tools import foo
```

```py
# tools.py
def foo():
    return 42
```

Now, when `import mymod`, I see that it has the following members:

```py
mymod.foo()
mymod.tools.foo()
```

I don't want the latter though; it just pollutes the namespace.

Funnily enough, if `tools.py` is called `foo.py` you get what you want:

```py
mymod.foo()
```

(Obviously, this only works if there is just one function per file.)

How do I avoid importing `tools`? Note that putting `foo()` into `__init__.py` is not an option. (In reality, there are *many* functions like `foo` which would absolutely clutter the file.)

Comment: If I understand what you are doing, this is somewhat similar in content to the question I had before: [Any way for python file name to not end up in fully qualified name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722449/any-way-for-python-file-name-to-not-end-up-in-fully-qualified-name), see if there's anything you can use there. I was basically told what I'm expecting is unPythonic and that I should be satisfied with `mymod.tools.foo()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of the `mymod.tools` attribute is crucial to maintaining proper function of the import system. One of the normal invariants of Python imports is that if a module `x.y` is registered in `sys.modules`, then the `x` module has a `y` attribute referring to the `x.y` module. Otherwise, things like

```
import x.y
x.y.y_function()
```

break, and depending on the Python version, even

```
from x import y
```

can break. Even if you don't think you're doing any of the things that would break, other tools and modules rely on these invariants, and trying to remove the attribute causes a slew of compatibility problems that are nowhere near worth it.

---

Trying to make `tools` not show up in your `mymod` module's namespace is kind of like trying to not make "private" (leading-underscore) attributes show up in your objects' namespaces. It's not how Python is designed to work, and trying to force it to work that way causes more problems than it solves.

The leading-underscore convention isn't just for instance variables. You could mark your `tools` module with a leading underscore, renaming it to `_tools`. This would prevent it from getting picked up by `from mymod import *` imports (unless you explicitly put it in an `__all__` list), and it'd change how IDEs and linters treat attempts to access it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `__init__.py` file:

```
from .tools import foo
del tools
```

Comment: This technically works, but causes nasty side effects that outweigh any minor benefit of removing one name from the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the `tools` module, it's just available when you import the package like you're doing:

```py
import mymod
```

You will have access to everything defined in the `__init__` file and all the modules of this package:

```py
import mymod

# Reference a module
mymod.tools

# Reference a member of a module
mymod.tools.foo

# And any other modules from this package
mymod.tools.subtools.func
```

When you import `foo` inside `__init__` you are are just making `foo` available there just like if you have defined it there, but of course you defined it in `tools` which is a way to organize your package, so now since you imported it inside `__init__` you can:

```py
import mymod

mymod.foo()
```

Or you can import `foo` alone:

```py
from mymod import foo

foo()
```

But you can import `foo` without making it available inside `__init__`, you can do the following which is exactly the same as the example above:

```py
from mymod.tools import foo

foo()
```

You can use both approaches, they're both right, in all these example you are not "cluttering the file" as you can see accessing `foo` using `mymod.tools.foo` is namespaced so you can have multiple `foo`s defined in other modules.

Comment: That's not what I want. I only want `mymod.foo()`, and because there are so many `foo`s, I want to put them in separate files instead of cramming them into `__init__.py`.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer You don't have to import all of them into the `__init__` file, you can just import the ones that you want to use directly like `mymod.foo()`, the other ones you can import them or use them by referencing them like `mymod.submod.foo()`. By importing `mymod` you are not making all the submodules and their members available, you can just reference them when you need them.

Comment: By "import" you mean copy-and-paste into it? No, there are too many, even the ones I want to make available to the outside. I must put them into separate files.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer No I don't mean copy and paste, I mean using the `import` keyword `import whatever.you.want`, I suggest you check out some popular Python repositories on Github and see how the projects are organized.