# What is the correct way to import the contents of a module at the top level when making a Python package?

Tags: python, import, package

I have a Python package that has the following standard structure.

```
pkg
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── pkg
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── mod.py
│       └── subpkg
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── submod.py
└── tests
```

The module `pkg/src/pkg/mod.py` contains the function `foo()`. I would like to be able to load `pkg/src/pkg/mod.py` at the top level so that I can call `foo()` with the following syntax.

```
>>> pkg.foo()
```

What is the correct way to do this? I am currently doing it by putting the following in `pkg/src/pkg/__init__.py`.

```
from .mod import *
from . import subpkg
```

But if I call `dir` on `pkg` then `mod.py` is listed as if the whole module has been imported and not just the functions it contains.

```
>>> dir(pkg)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'foo', 'mod', 'subpkg']
```

Is this to be expected? Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) describes how you can use `__all__` in this case to whitelist what is included when a package is imported using `*`.

Note that it also gently discourages using `...import *` as a general rule, in favor of explicitly importing each submodule you might need.

Comment: Thanks, Xanatosinc. But the `__all__` trick doesn't work. If I add `__all__ = ["subpkg", "foo"]` to `pkg/src/pkg/__init__.py` then I still see `mod.py` listed in `dir(pkg)`.

Comment: Whoops, I think I misread your question. Playing around with this I tried adding `del mod` to `pkg/src/pkg/__init__.py`, which works, but feels very wrong. There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595899/import-method-from-python-submodule-in-init-but-not-submodule-itself) with an accepted answer that might be helpful (TL;DR it's probably good and expected to have `mod` in the namespace).

Comment: Thank you so much for thinking about this for me. After some more thinking of my own I  believe I agree with you---having `mod` available as a module in its own right is the expected behaviour. I just wasn't expecting it. The answers to that SO question are very useful. A similar question was asked over in the Python discussion form ([here](https://discuss.python.org/t/why-do-relative-from-imports-also-add-the-submodule-itself-to-the-namespace/24440)). The conclusion seems to be the same: having `mod` added to the namespace is a natural consequence of `import` here.